# Extracting paper URLs from leaderboard HTML based on regular expression

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

## Problem

I am now moving into a natural language processing projects. Before I get my hands dirty, I plan to read other people's works on dataset, where they are organized as a [leaderboard](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/) (see "Three-way Classification" section).

However, in order to download these papers, I need to manually click on each URL (there are about 50 of them), which is time-consuming. Therefore, I am trying to extract these URLs from HTML, which looks like following:

```
<h3>Three-way classification</h3>

<blockquote>
<table class="newstuff">

<tr class="header">
<th>Publication</th>
<th>&nbsp;Model</th>
<th>Parameters</th>
<th>&nbsp;Train (% acc)</th>
<th>&nbsp;Test (% acc)</th>
</tr>

<tr class="section">
<th colspan="5" style="background-color:transparent; color:#646464;">Feature-based models</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">Bowman et al. '15</a></td>
<td>Unlexicalized features</td>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align: right">49.4</td>
<td style="text-align: right">50.4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">Bowman et al. '15</a></td>
<td>+ Unigram and bigram features</td>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align: right">99.7</td>
<td style="text-align: right"><em>78.2</em></td>
</tr>


<tr class="section">
<th colspan="5" style="background-color:transparent; color:#646464;">Sentence vector-based models</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">Bowman et al. '15</a></td>
<td>100D LSTM encoders</td>
<td style="text-align: right">220k</td>
<td style="text-align: right">84.8</td>
<td style="text-align: right">77.6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.nyu.edu/projects/bowman/spinn.pdf">Bowman et al. '16</a></td>
<td>300D LSTM encoders</td>
<td style="text-align: right">3.0m</td>
<td style="text-align: right">83.9</td>
<td style="text-align: right">80.6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06361v3.pdf">Vendrov et al. '15</a></td>
<td>1024D GRU encoders w/ unsupervised 'skip-thoughts' pre-training</td>
<td style="text-align: right">15m</td>
<td style="text-align: right">98.8</td>
<td style="text-align: right">81.4</td>
</tr>
...
```

I know I could use `requests` and `bs4.BeautifulSoup` to download and parse this page. But I could not figure out a way to extract URLs because there is not an easy to to pinpoint each individual row (there are other URLs outside of the table, so I could not say any URL extracted from the HTML is what I want).

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

## Update

The main difficulty is to extract URLs **only** from the leaderboard, which is tagged as

```
<h3>Three-way classification</h3>

<blockquote>
<table class="newstuff">
...

</table>
</blockquote>
```

Before and after this leaderboard, there are many contexts that is irrelevant to my purpose, where there are also a lot of URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression along with **findall()** method can be used for finding all the intersting links form the given html content.

BeautifulSoup offers an easy way to  read table from html.

The above goal of reading pdf links form a table inside a given html content can be achieved by using regex along with BeautifulSoup.

**Working example using regex and along with BeatifulSoup**

```
# File name: find-pdf-links.py

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlContent = """
    <h3>Three-way classification</h3>
    ...
    <td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">
    ...
    <td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">
    ....
    <td><a href="http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf">
    ......
    <td><a href="https://www.nyu.edu/projects/bowman/spinn.pdf">
    ...
    <td><a href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06361v3.pdf">
"""

# Read webpage
webPage = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent)

# Read table form the webpage
tableOfLinks = webPage.find("table")

print("PDF links:")
for link in tableOfLinks.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://.*pdf$")}):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

**Output:**

```
> python find-pdf-links.py

PDF links:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf
http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf
http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/snli_paper.pdf
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06361v3.pdf
```

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-url-string/

Comment: Thank you for your help! But as I said in the question, there are many URLs that are not part of the table. Is there a way to extract **only** the URLs from the table?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how the result can be achieved by using BeautifulSoup along with regex.